# Free Version app And Pro version App, Copy Xcode 6 Projects?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode6, app-store

I have an app, and I want to make a free version of an app and an pro version with No ads and added features. So should I just copy the folder and change the bundle identifier and stuff? I know about different targets and In App Purchases but I don't want to complicate stuff. If I use this method will it be a problem? secondly when I submit the app to App store, Do I have to mention it to them that one is pro version and one is free. If yes how, what exactly do I have to tell them,
Thanks,
Regards,
Aaryan

Comment: Best way is use the Xcode multiple targets feature.
Like project menu select New Target then you can then specify on a resource by resource basis which items are included in your target. You can switch between targets same like we switch between Simulators or device.Then According to the Target use can determine like which version you are compiling using #ifdef PRO or #ifdef LITE. But As per your requirement you can go and create copy of your project and make two apps on app store as well with required app store name as well like PRO or LITE. and submit them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can copy the same project n change Name & Bundle identifier.

Free: add the advertisement.
Pro: Do not add advertisement. set the .xib files such that advertisement space is not left.

You have to submit the binary code separately, and when you add the code, you will be asked about the price. You can select free or paid(also select the amount), whatever you want.

*if you only have inApp purchase in your PRO version and not the paid app, then select FREE when filling up details in itunesconnect.

**if your app supports inApp purchase, then you have to add details in the app detail section in your itunesconnect account.

FOR INAPP PURCHASE DETAILS:: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/technotes/tn2259/_index.html

FOR SUBMITTING APP TO ITUNESCONNECT:: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/LanguagesUtilities/Conceptual/iTunesConnect_Guide/Chapters/SubmittingTheApp.html